# Ubuntu: unable to install libapache2-svn

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, svn, apt, ubuntu-9.04

I get the following error when installing libapache2-svn on ubuntu 9.04.

```
root@....:~/install_scripts# apt-get install libapache2-svn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package libapache2-svn
root@......:~/install_scripts#
```

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates multiverse
```

contents of /etc/lsb-release

```
root@....:~/install_scripts# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=9.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jaunty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 9.04"
```

I tried replacing "hardy" by "jaunty" in /etc/apt/sources.list  but it did not work 
(I am confused with this karma/hardy/jaunty/kaola  etc. thing in ubuntu).

Please tell me the fix if you know.

thanks

JP

---

Note:  subversion and many other software installed fine:

```
root@....:~/install_scripts# apt-get install subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
subversion is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Try to update your list using: "sudo apt-get update".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The "hardy" in /etc/apt/sources.list definitely needed to be "jaunty". Also, I had to do

```
apt-get update; 
apt-get upgrade;
```

for the changes to be affected.